# How do I fit my data to a linear equation of known slope?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, data

I have some data that I would like to fit to a known linear equation of fixed slope but variable intercept. Say for the equation y=mx+c, I have experimentally obtained (x,y) data and know the value of m from theoretical models. I need the best value of c for my data set. 
Is there a way to do this other than brute force it by calculating c for each (x,y) and then averaging the values? Is there a statistically more accurate way of calculating the best fit? Thank you!

Comment: See `Fit` and `FindFit`.

Comment: Also, `LinearModelFit`.

Comment: And what do you mean by _calculating $c$ for each $(x,y)$_? How does $(1,2.3)$ define a $c$?

Comment: I know the value of m based on an established equation, and for my particular experiments the value of c could be different.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to do that with LinearModelFit, but I will try FindFit now and update this.Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the first example of `LinearModelFit`? We can't help much if you don't post any code. Also, to notify a user, prepend "@" to his name (e.g. @Ashwath).

Comment: how is `c` variable? is it correlated to `x`?

Answer (score 4):

***Update:***  I forgot to state that the estimator below is EXACTLY what you get from using `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`.  And while `LinearModelFit` has a `LinearOffsetFunction` that allows for known coefficients, it won't produce the desired output for this particular data and model.

If you really know the slope and know that the residual errors are normally distributed and have constant variance, then you could get an estimate of `c` with

```
Mean[y-m x]
```

But you'd be pretty unique if that were the case.  If you have lots of data, there's no reason to use that data to check on your assumptions and estimate `m` along with `c` (and look at the residuals to see if the assumption of constant variance is reasonable).

The standard error for the estimate of `c` is given by

```
StandardDeviation[y-m x]/Sqrt[Length[y]]
```

You won't get that from `FindFit` but if you replaced `FindFit` with `NonlinearModelFit` you could.

Comment: Yes, admittedly it is not a common situation to be in. I will consider this option as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For your kind of problem, [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) works well.

To illustrate how you would apply `FindFit`, I must first contrive some data with a little jitter.

```
SeedRandom[42]
With[{m = 3., c = 1.5, n = 10}, 
  data = 
    Table[
      {x, m x + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, .2]]}, 
      {x, Subdivide[0., 2., n]}]; 
   (* Compare the data to the line m x + c *)
   Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[m x + c, {x, 0, 2}]]]
```

[image: data]

Now I make the fit and compare it to the data.

```
With[{m = 3.},
  Module[{const},
    const = Block[{x, c}, FindFit[data, m x + c, c, x][[1, 2]]];
    Show[
      ListPlot[data],
      Plot[m x + const, {x, 0, 2}],
      Epilog -> {Text[Row[{"y-intercept = ", const}], Scaled[{.75, .25}]]}]]]
```

[image: fit]

Comment: Thank you! I think this looks like it is pretty much what I am looking for, though I'm trying to understand the syntax and implement this, will get back to you if I have more questions. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ashwath Just to clarify a little bit: `With[{m = 3.}, **stuff**,  FindFit[data, m x + c, c, x], **more stuff**]` means that `FindFit` is just doing `FindFit[data, 3. x + c, c, x]`. That is, it's finding the best `c` to fit `y == 3 x + c` to the data.

Comment: @aardvark2012, Thanks for the clarification - I understood that much, but wasn't able to figure out what the [[1,2]] appended to the FindFit line means. Would appreciate it if one of you can clarify that!

Comment: @Ashwath That just gives the actual value for `c` instead of the rule `c -> value`. Compare the outputs of `FindFit[data, 3. x + c, c, x]`, `FindFit[data, 3. x + c, c, x][[1]]` and `FindFit[data, 3. x + c, c, x][[1, 2]]`.

Comment: @ m_goldberg, @aardvark2012 : Got it to work, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some random data:

```
SeedRandom[1];

n = 30;
m = 3;
c = 10;

x = Range[0, n, 1];
y = (m * x + c) + RandomReal[{-3, 3}, n + 1];

data = Transpose[{x, y}];

ListLinePlot[data, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Now add the fit:

```
Clear[c, x];

model = m * x + c;
fit = FindFit[data, model, c, x];

Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {x, 0, n}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Fitting parameter:

```
c = c /. fit

9.81376
```

Comment: But that is not the maximum likelihood (or least squares) estimate of `c` when `m` is known.

Comment: I will correct  it ...

Comment: Perfect.  Same estimate as `Mean[data[[All, 2]] - m data[[All, 1]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is possible to discern *breaks* in your data and the variability in `c` is in fact due to a changing intercept, then using the following snippet, after adjusting it for the original data, should produce an estimate of the changing intercept

```
BlockRandom[

 With[{a1 = 1.01, b1 = 0.03, n = 100, h = 0.25},

   Module[{f = Floor[n/2], y1, y2, a2 = 2 a1, b2 = b1, y, cd, data, d},

    y1 = a1 + b1 Range[f] + h RandomReal[{b1 + a1, a1 + b1 f}, f];
    y2 = a2 + b2 Range[f + 1, n] + h RandomReal[{a2 + b2 (f + 1), a2 + b2 n}, n - f];
    y = Flatten[{y1, y2}, 1];

    cd = PadLeft[ConstantArray[1, n - f], n];

    data = Transpose[{cd, y}];

    lmf = LinearModelFit[data, {d}, {d}];

    ListPlot[{lmf["Response"], lmf["Response"] - lmf["FitResiduals"]},
      PlotLegends -> Placed[lmf["Function"][dummy], Above]]

    ]
   ], RandomSeeding -> 55477799]
```

For simulated data, one evaluation of the code produces

[image]

Adjusting the code to the standards of the question would require 1. to change `cd` and 2. change the dependent variable in `data`.

Changing `cd` requires one to identify the period of the break in the intercept and adjust `f` to that value. In the example, the break occurs in the middle of the sample, so `f=50` (`n=100` the sample size).

Please note that modifying the code above can allow for estimation of the slope parameter too, should that be desired (although not requested).

Changing the `data` to

```
data = Transpose[{cd, Range[n], y}]
```

where `Range[n]` should be replaced with the values of the independent variable (`x`) and modifying the call to `LinearModelFit` to read

```
 lmf = LinearModelFit[data, {d, x}, {d, x}];
```

we can incorporate more variables (besides the constant).

In this occasion, the output looks like the following graph

[image]